# How to stop or detach a container running without interactive or pseudo-TTY?

Tags: docker

I have a container running that I run using the command similar to the following

```
docker run user/container:latest /path/to/longrunningbinary
```

Now my container is running perpetually and I don't seem to have an ability to detach my shell from it. Tried <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> has no effect.

How do I detach or stop?

Comment: See if `CTRL+P, CTRL+Q` works for you

Comment: A really cheesy way might be:

    screen docker run user/container:latest /path/to/longrunningbinary

If it works, it would allow you to disconnect and later reconnect (if it's still running).

Comment: @TarunLalwani It didnt

Comment: Then probably disconnect the terminal and see if it goes to background. If you are worried about it being killed, you can try the same thing again with a new container